# function call dosen't seem to work in another function JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I can't quite figure out how to call the function correctly as shown. I want to replace all the repeditive code so that it gets it from my function info everytime.

Iv'e looked at other stackoverflow post and stuff but can't seem to figure it out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("option").click(function() {
    //alert("Value: " + $("#list").val());
    var foo = $("#list").val();

    if (foo == 1)
      $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=wlkCQXHEgjA&key=AIzaSyAqMJi5sUllzUPLVe6tbC557Lc_J5CmiFs&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status,topicDetails,player", function(data) {
        info(foo);
      });

    if (foo == 2)
      $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=_sBBaNYex3E&key=AIzaSyAqMJi5sUllzUPLVe6tbC557Lc_J5CmiFs&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status,topicDetails,player", function(data) {
        $('#headline').empty().append(data.items[0].snippet.title);
        $('#content').empty().append(data.items[0].player.embedHtml);
        $('#description').empty().append(data.items[0].snippet.description);
      });
      
    if (foo == 3)
      $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=kHBcVlqpvZ8&key=AIzaSyAqMJi5sUllzUPLVe6tbC557Lc_J5CmiFs&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status,topicDetails,player", function(data) {
        $('#headline').empty().append(data.items[0].snippet.title);
        $('#content').empty().append(data.items[0].player.embedHtml);
        $('#description').empty().append(data.items[0].snippet.description);
      });
  });
});

function info(foo) {
  $('#headline').empty().append(data.items[0].snippet.title);
  $('#content').empty().append(data.items[0].player.embedHtml);
  $('#description').empty().append(data.items[0].snippet.description);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list">
  <option value="1">Spot Launch</option>
  <option value="2">More Parkour Atlas</option>
  <option value="3">UpTown Spot</option>
  <option value="4">Handle Robot Reimagined for Logistics</option>
  <option value="5">What's new, Atlas?</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<div id="content"></div>
<h1 id="headline"></h1>
<div id="description"></div>
```

Comment: which function u need to call?

Comment: the function info

Comment: can you add the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to do something like this in order to avoid the repetition 
 (that's how I understood your "replace boilerplate"?

```
function info(foo) {
    $('#headline').empty().append(foo.items[0].snippet.title);
    $('#content').empty().append(foo.items[0].player.embedHtml);
    $('#description').empty().append(foo.items[0].snippet.description);
}
```

and then utilise it as follows

```
$.get('your_url', function(data) {
    info(data);
});
```

Comment: nope, he is duplicating the code within the `info` function instead of using it; (see the `foo` variable being passed as param but never used - hence my assumption)

Answer (score 1):

`<option>` does not react to clicks and does not emit click events. Instead, use `$("select").change(...)` and your code works. The function `foo` gets called. However, `data` is not defined inside of it, so you need to pass it along as you call the function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("select").change(function() {
    //alert("Value: " + $("#list").val());
    var foo = $("#list").val();

    if (foo == 1)
      $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=wlkCQXHEgjA&key=AIzaSyAqMJi5sUllzUPLVe6tbC557Lc_J5CmiFs&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status,topicDetails,player", function(data) {
        info(foo, data);
      });

    if (foo == 2)
      $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=_sBBaNYex3E&key=AIzaSyAqMJi5sUllzUPLVe6tbC557Lc_J5CmiFs&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status,topicDetails,player", function(data) {
        $('#headline').empty().append(data.items[0].snippet.title);
        $('#content').empty().append(data.items[0].player.embedHtml);
        $('#description').empty().append(data.items[0].snippet.description);
      });
      
    if (foo == 3)
      $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=kHBcVlqpvZ8&key=AIzaSyAqMJi5sUllzUPLVe6tbC557Lc_J5CmiFs&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status,topicDetails,player", function(data) {
        $('#headline').empty().append(data.items[0].snippet.title);
        $('#content').empty().append(data.items[0].player.embedHtml);
        $('#description').empty().append(data.items[0].snippet.description);
      });
  });
});

function info(foo, data) {
  $('#headline').empty().append(data.items[0].snippet.title);
  $('#content').empty().append(data.items[0].player.embedHtml);
  $('#description').empty().append(data.items[0].snippet.description);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list">
  <option value="1">Spot Launch</option>
  <option value="2">More Parkour Atlas</option>
  <option value="3">UpTown Spot</option>
  <option value="4">Handle Robot Reimagined for Logistics</option>
  <option value="5">What's new, Atlas?</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<div id="content"></div>
<h1 id="headline"></h1>
<div id="description"></div>
```